# React apollo hooks fails after adding react-native to monorepo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, apollo, monorepo

I am trying to create a React web app and React-native app with monorepo by using yarn workspaces. So I created web and controllers and it works fine. I was able to make graphql queries to my apollo-express server. But, after adding react-native application I see this:
[image]

I am 100% that I am not breaking any react hooks rules because before adding react-native application it was work fine.

Is there any way how can I solve it?

Apollo controller

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const useHelloQuery = () => useQuery(
     gql`
         {
             hello
         }
     `
)
```

React component:

```
function Test() {
     const data = useHelloQuery();

     return (
          <Text>awesoe</Text>
     );
}
```

before adding react-native it was exactly same

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you call `useQuery` because that's not the correct way of using hooks.

and you don't have to worry about manually triggering the api call, `useQuery` will handle that for you.

```
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

function Test() {
     const response = useQuery(
     gql`
         {
             hello
         }
     `)

     return (
          <Text>awesoe</Text>
     );
}
```